# Can we use OMX to do video encode on android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, openmax

There is a 'native-media' project in NDK samples, in which it calls OMX functions in C level to do the video decode and play stuff, but it seems that NDK doesn't support encode of OMX now, is that true?

Besides, I also find this [link](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdevnet-forums/multimedia-optimization-qdsp/12520). It seems that people are talking about use OMX to do video encode. But I can't find more information about OMX encode in android. Does anyone know about that?

Answer (score 0):

We can do that in certain condition.

Google doesn't provide the API for native-media encoder now. If we want to do that, we need to use the code provided by the hardware company, compile the code into a `.so` file, and call the function through that file in NDK.

I've found a sample provided by Qualcomm. You can find it in this [link](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdevnet-forums/multimedia-optimization-qdsp/12520). After you download the sample, you will find a user introduction and a demo.